# Problem about Probability theory : marginal density.

Tags: probability-theory

I'm studying 'Probability theory' and I cannot figure out the way to find marginal density.

The problem is :

Take A to be the square with corners at (0,1), (1,0), (2,1), (1,2). Find the marginal densities of f = indicator function of A.

The solution is :

> Fix $x \in [0,2], \int_0^2 \mathbf{1}_A (x,y)\, dy = m(A_x)$, hence $$
> f_X(x) = 
> \begin{cases}
> x, ~\text{for}~x \in [0,1] \\
> 2-x, ~\text{for}~x \in [1,2] \\
> 0, \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases} 
> $$(triangle distribution). By symmetry, the same holds for $f_Y$.

I cannot figure out how to find f_X(x) with integral part!

I think f_X(x) should be '2x' for x in [0,1], 4-2x for x in (1,2], and 0 for otherwise.

Please give me some advice!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The joint distribution is uniform on the square $A$,

[image]

Thus

$$f_{XY}(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}\mathbb{1}_{[(x,y)\in A]}$$

Then do a drawing and calculate the marginal $f_X(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x,y)dy$

1. When $0<X<1$ the integral is the following

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1-x}^{x+1}dy=x$$

2. When $1<X<2$ the integral is the following

$$f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{x-1}^{3-x}dy=2-x$$

The result is a triangular distribution that you can write in a more compact way

$$f_X(x)=[1-|1-x|]\cdot\mathbb{1}_{[0;2]}(x)$$

Same result for $f_Y(y)$ using symmetry properties